# Why isn't cxfreeze turning my code into an executable file?

Tags: executable, cx-freeze

I get this error whenever I try to turn my Python code into an executable.

I tried the documentation, but I couldn't find anything similar to this error.

Everywhere I looked, I couldn't find anyone with this kind of error!

Could anyone help me? I've tried using pyinstaller as well, but it keeps giving me problems with Windows Defender, so I've come to the conclusion that it's better to try to fix this error with cxfreeze.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTlmj.png)

I haven't tried anything technical because I'm new to python, so if anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it